# Codility voracious fish are moving along a river

Tags: c#, algorithm, stack

I am trying to solve the codility problem:

> N voracious fish are moving along a river. Calculate how many fish are alive.

[Codility Problem](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/7-stacks_and_queues/fish/)

My code get only 50 percent of 100. Could you tell me what is wrong with my code?

> You are given two non-empty zero-indexed arrays A and B consisting of
>   N integers. Arrays A and B represent N voracious fish in a river,
>   ordered downstream along the flow of the river.
>
> The fish are numbered from 0 to N − 1. If P and Q are two fish and P <
>   Q, then fish P is initially upstream of fish Q. Initially, each fish
>   has a unique position.
>
> Fish number P is represented by A[P] and B[P]. Array A contains the
>   sizes of the fish. All its elements are unique. Array B contains the
>   directions of the fish. It contains only 0s and/or 1s, where:
>
> 0 represents a fish flowing upstream, 1 represents a fish flowing
>   downstream. If two fish move in opposite directions and there are no
>   other (living) fish between them, they will eventually meet each
>   other. Then only one fish can stay alive − the larger fish eats the
>   smaller one. More precisely, we say that two fish P and Q meet each
>   other when P < Q, B[P] = 1 and B[Q] = 0, and there are no living fish
>   between them. After they meet:
>
> If A[P] > A[Q] then P eats Q, and P will still be flowing downstream.
>   If A[Q] > A[P] then Q eats P, and Q will still be flowing upstream. We
>   assume that all the fish are flowing at the same speed. That is, fish
>   moving in the same direction never meet. The goal is to calculate the
>   number of fish that will stay alive.
>
> For example, consider arrays A and B such that:
>
> ```
> A[0] = 4    B[0] = 0
> A[1] = 3    B[1] = 1
> A[2] = 2    B[2] = 0
> A[3] = 1    B[3] = 0
> A[4] = 5    B[4] = 0
> ```
>
> Initially all the fish are alive and all except fish number 1 are
>   moving upstream. Fish number 1 meets fish number 2 and eats it, then
>   it meets fish number 3 and eats it too. Finally, it meets fish number
>   4 and is eaten by it. The remaining two fish, number 0 and 4, never
>   meet and therefore stay alive.
>
> Write a function:
>
> ```
> class Solution { public int solution(int[] A, int[] B); }
> ```
>
> that, given two non-empty zero-indexed arrays A and B consisting of N
>   integers, returns the number of fish that will stay alive.
>
> For example, given the arrays shown above, the function should return
>   2, as explained above.
>
> Assume that:
>
> N is an integer within the range [1..100,000]; each element of array A
>   is an integer within the range [0..1,000,000,000]; each element of
>   array B is an integer that can have one of the following values: 0, 1;
>   the elements of A are all distinct.
>
> Complexity:
>
> Expected worst-case time complexity is O(N); expected worst-case space
>   complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the storage
>   required for input arguments).

This is my algorithm:

```
public static int solution(int[] size, int[] direction)
{
    var stack = new Stack<int>();
    const int UPSTREAM = 0;
    const int DOWNSTREAM = 1;
    var updateStack = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < size.Length; i++)
    {
        if (stack.Count <= 0) //initial data
            stack.Push(i);
        else
        {
            var lastFish = stack.Peek();

            if (direction[i] == direction[lastFish] || direction[lastFish] == UPSTREAM && direction[i] == DOWNSTREAM) 
            {
                stack.Push(i);
            }
            else
            {
                while (stack.Count > 0 && size[lastFish] < size[i] && direction[lastFish] == DOWNSTREAM && direction[i] == UPSTREAM)
                {
                    updateStack = true;
                    stack.Pop();
                    if (stack.Count > 0)
                        lastFish = stack.Peek();
                }
                if (updateStack)
                {
                    stack.Push(i);
                    updateStack = false;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return stack.Count;
}
```

Comment: Questions containing broken code or asking for advice about code not yet written are off-topic, as the code is not ready for review. After the question has been edited to contain working code, we will consider reopening it.

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: If it still only solves 50%, it's not fixed. Please clarify. Did you read the [help/on-topic]?

Comment: Yes, i got only 50% of the total score

Comment: That means the code still doesn't work as intended and it's not ready for review. Please take a look at the links provided.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a situation where good naming is your friend. Instead of parameters `A` and `B`, and magic numbers `0` and `1`, and the rather long-winded expression `stack.Peek()`, I suggest you start by installing some useful names:

```
const int UPSTREAM = 0;
const int DOWNSTREAM = 1;

public static int solution(int[] size, int[] direction)
{
    var stack = new Stack<int>();
    var updateStack = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < size.Length; i++)
    {
        if (stack.Count <= 0) //initial data
            stack.Push(i);
        else
        {
            var lastFish = stack.Peek();

            if (direction[i] == direction[lastFish] 
             || direction[i] != direction[lastFish] 
                && direction[lastFish] == UPSTREAM 
                && direction[i] == DOWNSTREAM) 
            {
                stack.Push(i);
            }
            else
            {
                while (stack.Count > 0 
                       && size[lastFish] < size[i] 
                       && direction[lastFish] == DOWNSTREAM 
                       && direction[i] == UPSTREAM)
                {
                    updateStack = true;
                    stack.Pop();
                    lastFish = stack.Peek();
                }
                if (updateStack)
                    stack.Push(i);
            }
        }

    }
    return stack.Count;
}
```

This shows me there is some confusion on your part. You are allowed to assume that a *logical or* (`||`) fails because it's false - there's no need to repeat the test in a false mode:

```
if (direction[i] == direction[lastFish] 
 || direction[i] != direction[lastFish] && ...
```

Instead, just assume that failure implies failure, and go on:

```
if (direction[i] == direction[lastFish] 
  || direction[lastFish] == UPSTREAM 
     && direction[i] == DOWNSTREAM)
```

Furthermore, you can assume that since you know the directions are different, and since you know there are only two directions, testing one of them is enough:

```
if (direction[i] == direction[lastFish] || direction[i] == DOWNSTREAM)
```

That said, I notice that you initialize `updateStack` to `false` *outside of your loop* and never reset it to `false` anyplace else. This means that once you've set `updateStack = true`, it will stay true forever (inside you loop, anyway). That's probably the source of your error, because it should stop being true once you've updated the stack.

Comment: Thanks for help; I updated the code now according to your suggestion but still doesn't work properly

Comment: I got only 50% of total score